# synchronize emulator realtime

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any control or any facility in android that if we have start that, after it any change in layout or in code ,it directly update into emulator. without run.

thanks

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no tool available for this.

Comment: you have graphical layout. here you can check your layout. How it looks. Also if you have device of different resolution, size, density you can create custom graphical layout for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android emulator has the full android firmware running inside a QEMU virtual machine. If there would be a way to do it for the emulator, most probably there would be for real devices as well. But unfortunately there isn't.